# How can I troubleshoot VirtualBox port forwarding from Windows guest to Mac OS X host not working?

Tags: virtualbox

There is a plethora of questions about VirtualBox port forwarding problems but none with my specific details. 
Details of setup:

I have a Windows 7 Professional 64bit install living in VirtualBox 4.1.2, hosted within Mac OS X 10.6.8. I’ve got several webservers running on `localhost` on different ports within the Windows install. I cannot for the life of me get port forwarding to work so I can access those webservers from Mac OS X.

My settings look like this; yes I have a NAT adapter:

[image]

And in my VirtualBox configuration file the relavent portion looks like this:

```
<NAT>
  <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
  <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
  <Forwarding name="RLPWeb" proto="1" hostport="7084" guestip="127.0.0.1" guestport="7084"/>
  <Forwarding name="UtilWeb" proto="1" hostport="4040" guestip="127.0.0.1" guestport="4040"/>
  <Forwarding name="WCARLP" proto="1" hostport="8084" guestip="127.0.0.1" guestport="8084"/>
  <Forwarding name="WCAUtil" proto="1" hostport="4848" guestip="127.0.0.1" guestport="4848"/>
</NAT>
```

I’ve turned off the Windows firewall to ensure it is not interfering, and I am not running a firewall on Mac OS X.

Anyway, when I attempt to go to for example `http://127.0.0.1:4040/` on any of my Mac OS X browsers, it will eventually time out.

The log file for this VM shows that it is correctly reading the settings and implying it's doing the right thing here:

```
00:00:08.286 NAT: set redirect TCP host port 4848 => guest port 4848 @ 127.0.0.1
00:00:08.286 NAT: set redirect TCP host port 8084 => guest port 8084 @ 127.0.0.1
00:00:08.286 NAT: set redirect TCP host port 4040 => guest port 4040 @ 127.0.0.1
00:00:08.286 NAT: set redirect TCP host port 7084 => guest port 7084 @ 127.0.0.1
00:00:08.290 Changing the VM state from 'LOADING' to 'SUSPENDED'.
00:00:08.290 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDED' to 'RESUMING'.
00:00:08.290 Changing the VM state from 'RESUMING' to 'RUNNING'.
00:00:08.337 Display::handleDisplayResize(): uScreenId = 0, pvVRAM=000000012017d000 w=1834 h=929 bpp=32 cbLine=0x1CA8, flags=0x1
00:00:09.139 AIOMgr: Host limits number of active IO requests to 16. Expect a performance impact.
00:00:13.454 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
```

I’ve tried setting the Host IP to `127.0.0.1`, and I’ve tried setting Guest IP blank and also `10.0.2.15`. None of these seem to help.

What else can I look at to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I don't think you need to set the guest IP unless you have assigned a static IP to the guest so leaving it blank is probably right.

Comment: You should enter the actual IP of the guest machine - IIRC the NAT default is `10.0.2.5` - not 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed problems with port forwards on macOS X VirtualBox host.

Using network adapter PCnet-Fast III (Am79C973) and Oracle Developer Day image as guest.

When ever I suspend the guest and resume it all port forwards are lost.

I am not certain if the problems are related to the network adapter or to the guest but I fail to see how the guest could be aware of the port forwards.

This is a long shot, but if you have anything in common with this case, *try shutting down (complete power off of the guest) and starting up with the port forwards set*. Immediately test if any of the port forwards work and only after positive results try suspending and resuming the guest.

Comment: I have tried exactly what you suggest, sadly there is no difference in behavior.

Comment: Have you tried adding 0.0.0.0 as the host ip in NAT settings?

Comment: Yes, I did try that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bridging the connection from the windows vm out to the Mac? Being under Network Address Translation NAT has proven to be a headache for me as well when inside a VM. Having a bridge provides the VM with an IP that the host can see. Given your port forwarding situation this shouldn't be an issue but I would try to forward ports from actual IPs rather than translated ones.

Answer (score 0):

According to the VirtualBox official documentation, the preferred way to do this is with your network mode set to Host-Only or Bridged.

**tl;dr:** Use Bridged, not NAT.

src: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html